# Track down where max_execution_time is being set in a PHP application

Tags: php, vagrant

I've got a `max_execution_time` which is stubbornly refusing to be changed despite changing the setting in the php.ini file that the webserver is reporting it uses.

Digging further I found it's also loading a `php-custom.ini` which also contains a `max_execution_time` setting. Changing this still does not change the reported setting.

I've checked for an .htaccess file - there isn't.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try fulltext search via all your project, maybe set_time_limit is called somewhere?

Comment: Well, honestly now, since it can be literally placed anywhere, you'll have to search the whole root folder of your project. `grep` is your friend. Since you're using vagrant, it should be pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

There are several timeouts you can configure:

In php.ini:

```
max_execution_time
```

If you use php-fpm, theres this one in the www.conf

```
request_terminate_timeout
```

If you use Nginx, there is this one in the vhost-file:

```
fastcgi_read_timeout
```